# Adding members to self hosted Gitlab account not working

Tags: gitlab

I have set up a self-hosted gitlab instance on docker windows it is also accessible from other machines with IP address. I am the root user I can log in perfectly. But **when I invite other members to my project** repository through email it does not work. They **don't get the invitation** to join the project.

Anyone who has faced the same issue or know what can be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, GitLab sends mail via the system `sendmail` command. This works if `sendmail` command is available and properly configured to send mail (via Postfix, etc).

You can also configure GitLab to use SMTP directly. See [SMTP documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/smtp.html) for help configuring SMTP.